# Faces Servlet not getting called for a specific page, blank page is rendering?

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jboss, icefaces

I have `icefaces` application and challenge i have in here is that `facesServlet` is not called from `application.xhtml` page but when i call it from `test.xhtml` page then that page renders fine but in case of `application.xhtml`, blank page shows up but doing view source you get to see the file.

**application.xhtml Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">
    <h:head>
        <title>Job Application</title>
        <ice:outputStyle href="./xmlhttp/css/xp/xp.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

    <ice:form partialSubmit="true">
        <ice:messages globalOnly="true" />

        <ice:panelGrid columns="3">
            <ice:outputLabel for="firstName" value="#{msgs.firstName}:" />
            <ice:inputText id="firstName" value="#{applicant.firstName}" required="true"/>
            <ice:message for="firstName" />

            <ice:outputLabel for="lastName" value="#{msgs.lastName}:" />
            <ice:inputText id="lastName" required="true" value="#{applicant.lastName}" />
            <ice:message for="lastName" />

            <ice:outputLabel for="travelPercentage" value="#{msgs.travelPercentage}:" />
            <ice:inputText id="travelPercentage" required="true" value="#{applicant.travelPercentage}">
                <f:validateLongRange minimum="0" maximum="100" />
            </ice:inputText>

            <ice:message for="travelPercentage" />

            <ice:outputLabel for="dateOfBirth" value="#{msgs.dateOfBirth}:" />
            <ice:selectInputDate id="dateOfBirth" required="true" value="#{applicant.dateOfBirth}"
                                     renderAsPopup="true">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
            </ice:selectInputDate>
            <ice:message for="dateOfBirth" />

            <ice:outputLabel for="city" value="#{msgs.city}" />
            <ice:inputText id="city" required="true" value="#{applicant.city}"/>
            <ice:message for="city" />

            <ice:outputLabel for="provinceId" value="#{msgs.provinceId}" />

                <ice:selectOneMenu id="provinceId"
                                 required="true"
                                 value="#{applicant.provinceId}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msgs.select}" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{provinceSupport.selectItems}" />
                </ice:selectOneMenu>
            <ice:message for="provinceId" />

            <ice:outputLabel for="postalCode" value="#{msgs.postalCode}" />
            <ice:inputText id="postalCode"
                             required="true" value="#{applicant.postalCode}"/>
            <ice:message for="postalCode" />
        </ice:panelGrid>

        <ice:panelGrid columns="1">
            <ice:commandLink value="#{applicantForm.resumeRendered ? msgs.hideResume : msgs.showResume}"
                             actionListener="#{applicantForm.toggleResume}"
                             immediate="true"/>

            <ice:inputTextarea id="resume" value="#{applicant.resume}" cols="40" rows="8"
                               rendered="#{applicantForm.resumeRendered}"/>
        </ice:panelGrid>

        <ice:commandButton value="#{msgs.submitApplication}" action="#{applicantForm.submit}"
                           partialSubmit="false"/>
    </ice:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

**test.xhtml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">
    <h:head><title>Thank You</title></h:head>
    <h:body>

    <ice:form>
        <ice:outputText value="Thank you #{applicant.firstName} for applying" />
        <br />
        <ice:commandButton action="submitAnother" value="Submit Another" />
    </ice:form>
     </h:body>
</html>
```

**Servlets and Servlet Mappings Information:**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Not sure what is causing the issue but `application.xhtml` is not hitting `facesServlet` also when i have mapping for `facesServlet` as `*.jsf` then i would not able to get to both pages but if i do `*.xhtml` then `test.xhtml` page would hit `facesServlet` but `application.xhtml` would not hit, not sure what is the issue in here.

**Update**

I guess and am not sure here that

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, might be causing the problem, i have my `test.xhtml` page as under:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">
        <h:head><title>Thank You</title></h:head>
        <h:body>

        <ice:form>
            <ice:outputText value="Thank you #{applicant.firstName} for applying" />
            <br />
            <ice:commandButton action="submitAnother" value="Submit Another" />
        </ice:form>

        </h:body>
    </html>
```

but when i deploy it and click on that page on `browser` nothing shows up and if i click view source then i have

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">
        <h:head><title>Thank You</title></h:head>
        <h:body>

        <ice:form>
            <ice:outputText value="Thank you #{applicant.firstName} for applying" />
            <br />
            <ice:commandButton action="submitAnother" value="Submit Another" />
        </ice:form>

        </h:body>
    </html>
```

I am not sure if `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` could cause the problem or not but view source put's that xml tag in which it's not present in original xhtml page, also i have checked `web.xml` file present deployed in the server and it does have `facesServlet` mapped properly also we do not have any filter that is doing some crazy stuffs.

Comment: What if you copy content of test.xhtml into application.xhtml? Does it then also fail? Perhaps you've an overzealous servlet `Filter` configured on an URL pattern matching `application.xhtml`.

Comment: @BalusC: I did clean build and deploy again with both pages having same code and now none of those pages are rendered, we only get blank page but when i do view source then i do get xhtml stuff but it is not parsed html.

Comment: @BalusC: I added same code on both the pages and tried to do fresh build and not both page show blank, checked `web.xml` in deployed folder and it does have `facesServletMapping` and also checked for filter's and we do have any filter's doing crazy stuffs out there.

Comment: How are you opening the page? In a normal webbrowser by a `http://` request, right? And thus not from local disk file system by `file://`?

Comment: i am opening it by `http://` only.

Comment: @BalusC: if i copy the content of test.xhtml to application.xhtml then application.xhtml page renders fine, i guess something is wrong with original application.xhtml page.

Comment: @BalusC: I was able to get the pages but now if page has reference to css files present in icefaces jar then those pages are not rendered but for other pages, rendering seems to be fine.

Comment: Well, seems to be ICEfaces specific.

Comment: @Rachel have you resolved this  ?